# Как передать данные с одного активити в другое, при том чтобы они сохранялись в обеих Activity до удаления приложения. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу передать данные выбранные из поля Name, Surname и Спиннеров с Activity 1 в Activity 2. При том чтобы эти данные сохранялись в приложении до её удаления. Как это сделать? Можно ли это сделать с помощью Shared Preferences? Я Знаю что данные передавать можно с помощью Intent но они там не сохраняются. Скажите пожалуйста как это реализовать хорошим образом? Спасибо вам ОГРОМНОЕ заранее!

Comment: Shared Preferences вполне подойдут.

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить данные на устройстве можно тремя способами.

- SharedPrference служит для хранения простых данных.
- База данных. В ней вы можете хранить более сложные объекты вашего приложения. Вы можете доставать этим данные выборочно, так как вам будет удобно. База данных хранится во внутренней дериктории приложения.
- Сохранить на файл. Это даст вам возможность шарить данные за пределами приложения.
- На удаленном сервере. Это позволит вам шарить данные за пределами устройства. Но потребует больших затрат.

Если вам необходимо сохранить только имена то SharedPrference вам вполне подойдёт. Если же вы захотите хранить более сложные структуры, я рекомендую использовать бд или другие способы хранения данных.